Closed form for the partial sums of the Harmonic Series?
I just realized that the nth partial sum of the Harmonic series is equivalent to the absolute value of the quotient of the coefficient of the linear term divided by the constant term of the polynomial whose roots  are the first n natural numbers.
I don’t have time right now to show proof but this is fairly obvious given Vieta’s formulas. (However, I searched for a connection between the partial sums of the Harmonic Series and Vieta’s formulas and found nothing.)
The statement above is nothing remarkable. The mechanics of calculating the absolute value of the linear term of the polynomial as described is identical to the process of finding the numerator of the nth partial sum of the Harmonic Series. The constant term is, of course, just n factorial.
That got me thinking, again, about a closed form solution. I played around with that idea while in school and I am now curious:
Has anyone proven if it is impossible to find a ‘nice’ closed form? If not, what is the consensus among mathematicians that a closed form exists?
EDIT: I guess by nice I mean in terms of elementary functions. Sorry, I should have been clearer.
By elementary functions I do mean polynomials, quotients of polynomials, and exponentials (as well as logarithms) as Jan suggested.

I doubt that it can be proven that there is no "nice" closed form , but I also doubt that there is such a "nice" closed form for the exact solution (of course we can establish very good approximations , in particular for large $n$).

If the denominator is $n!$ then the numerator is OEIS A000254

You looked up the wikipedia article on the topic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community, it is plenty clear what OP is asking, whether there is a nice answer to it or not! Wonder what algorithm you run on for coming up with such wisdom :)

What is your definition of “nice”? I’m curious since, depending on what that definition is, it might be reasonable to prove that no such formula exists. I recommend you to make an edit to your post to define “nice”.

@Srini Always if unsharp terminology is used as "much smaller" , "approximation " , "nice" , "pattern" , "rule" , "useful" and more , without an explicite mathematical definition what is meant in the current question , such questions are in fact unclear. There is too much room for subjectivity to make it a math question suitable for this site. Note that this is not a site for discussions.

What do you consider “elementary”? Polynomials, quotients of polynomials and exponential functions?

@Jan I edited my question but you were correct in your assumption. Sorry for the vague question.
